# Use Round function within VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

This function returns multiple lookup matches within one cell:

```
Function NBlookup(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)
Dim result As String
Dim x As Range

result = ""
For Each x In lookuprange
    If x = lookupval Then
        result = result & " " & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1) & x.Offset(0, 5)
    End If
Next x
NBlookup = result
End Function
```

The following part concatenates it with a number value:

```
& x.Offset(0, 5)
```

I want to roundup the value: `if & x.Offset(0, 5) >= 5 then` roundup, otherwise round down.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Force it to an integer

Comment: `iif( x.Offset(0, 5) >=5,application.worksheetfunction.roundup( x.Offset(0, 5),0),application.worksheetfunction.rounddown( x.Offset(0, 5) ,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Round()` function, like this : `Round(x.Offset(0, 5), 0)`

After re-reading your post, it seems that you are trying to round up or down, around 5 and not 0.5
If that's the case, I'll do some thing like this : `Round(x.Offset(0, 5)/10, 0)*10`

```
Public Function NBlookup(lookUpVal, lookUpRange As Range, indexCol As Long)
    Dim Result As String
    Dim x As Range

    Result = ""
    For Each x In lookUpRange
        If x = lookUpVal Then
            Result = Result & " " & x.Offset(0, indexCol - 1) & Round(x.Offset(0, 5), 0)
        End If
    Next x
    NBlookup = Result
End Function
```

---

I've added a few Caps in your variables' names (lower camel case), to see a bit much what is what.

I've also declare your function as `Public` so that you can use it in Excel cells directly. Anyhow it is a good practice to declare the scope (Public, Private, Friend) of your functions or subs. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `& x.Offset(0, 5)` with

```
& Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(x.Offset(0, 5),0)
```

Comment: Any particular reason to recommend the worksheet function rather than the VBA one ?

Comment: @R3uK To be honest, not at all, lol. It's definitely a personal fixation. I'm afraid i cannot think any particular reason to recomment the worksheet function rather than the VBA one in this case, because both of them round applying banking rules.

Comment: NP, I asked because I know I should use WF more as most of them are really efficient ;)